# Select image region

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, android-image

I am looking for a way to do something similar to the image at the bottom. However, I need the selection area to go all the way across and be able to be moved up and down the image via touch.  I just need to get the coordinates of the selected pixels.

I am assuming I will need to create a canvas and draw the image background, but after that I'm pretty lost.  If anyone can provide an example of something like this, or just a basic walkthrough on what to read up on I would really appreciate it.

[image]

Comment: Are you planning to apply cropping feature?

Comment: No, at least not on the client.  I just need the user to select a region and then i send the full image, and the pixel offsets to the server, which does some image manipulation

Comment: @TheGeekNess is there any update on this question? I'm looking for library with such functionality